# Дублируется результат запроса

Tags: mysql, sql

Задача сортировать (ORDER BY) врачей из таблицы clinic по самой низкой цене price из таблицы doctor_clinic_offer, проблема в том что у врача могут быть несколько предложений цен от клиник и если использовать LEFT JOIN, то результаты дублируются так как предложений цены несколько...

```
SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "doctor_to_clinic d2cl LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "clinic c ON (d2cl.clinic_id = c.clinic_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "doctor_clinic_offer dco ON (c.clinic_id = dco.clinic_id) WHERE d2cl.doctor_id = '" . (int)$doctor_id . "' ORDER BY dco.price
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.doctor_name, s.min_price
FROM clinic c
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id, min(price) AS min_price
FROM doctor_clinic_offer 
GROUP BY id) as dсo
on c.id = dсo.id
ORDER BY min_price
```

Comment: не совсем то, если добавить джоином другие таблицы то дублирование опять

Comment: @ДенисЛинник Скорее всего не в том порядке или неверно объединяются таблицы. Еще есть оператор DISTINCT для удаления дублирующих строк